# mvn test does not find JUnit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, maven, junit

I have a a test class which is named `xxxTest.java` so the test class if found. But the unit tests within the class are not run when I execute `mvn test`.

I am using JUnit 4 and the test method's are annotated with `@Test`. eg.

```
@Test
public void shouldDoSomeAsserting() {
    // unit test impl
}
```

If I rename that test method so it is name `testShouldDoSomeAsserting()` then `mvn test` does find and execute that unit test.

I was under the impression that when I use `@Test` as long as the method was public and void that it would be considered a test method.

Have I missed something?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you modified the configuration of the `maven-surefire-plugin` in your pom.xml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got it working by manually specifying a provider; more details here: [Surefire JUnit 4 config](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html)

Answer (score 2):

Are you absolutely sure you are using JUnit 4? This sounds like JUnit 3 behaviour.

I made a minimal sample project and I couldn't recreate your problem. The test runs as expected.

The sample project is here: https://gist.github.com/1888802

Maybe you can get some kind of hint from it.

Comment: Yes, 100%, I'm using 4.7 to be exact.

Comment: Is your test class extending TestCase?

Comment: Nope, I'm using @RunWith so no need. I figured it out though, see my answer.